# Button with background image text positioning

Tags: android, xml, button

I would like to position the text in my button like this:

[image]

At the moment the text is positioned in the bottom left corner of the button:

[image]

I have four rows of this type of buttons and in every row there is two buttons. Here is my code for one row of buttons:

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_fashion_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/thumbnail_channel_fashion"
                android:text="Fashion"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_science_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/thumbnail_channel_science"
                android:text="Science"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

how can I add some padding to the left and below of the text without moving the background image? Margin seems to add white space around button and padding creates space between background image and button's edges.

Thanks for help!

Comment: you can use imagebutton

Comment: just add padding/margin to the button.

Comment: Text does not show in imagebutton://

Comment: Margin just creates white space around the button and padding makes white space between background image and button's edges

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_fashion_button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:text="Fashion"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="10dp">
```

Comment: This just adds some white space between backgroundimage and top edge://

Comment: Yeah that I could do, but would not like to add extra levels to my code

Comment: is it the only choice?

Comment: @Leero11 you can use this.

Comment: Didn't work in my code://  I have two boxes of this type in every line, so probably not working because of it. Because of it I have the gravity 1

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
        android:text="FASHION"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```